# Capture the close event of popup window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to perform some action before a popup window(using `window.open` ) closes.

Something like will be good:

```
var new_window = window.open('some url')
new_window.onBeforeUnload = function(){ my code}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Your example will work **as long as the pop-up window url is in the same domain as the parent** page, and you change the event to all lowercase:

```
var new_window = window.open('some url')
new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ /* my code */ }
```

Comment: What if the newly opened window is not in the same domain with the parent window? Is there any hack?

Comment: The best you could do is open a document in your domain that then loads the remote URL in an iframe, or reads it in via server scripts and renders it from there.

Comment: @glortho Does this approach has any advantage over defining the onbeforeunload event inside the new_window? More specifically, if this will bind the code immediately with the new_window, even before the new_page and it's scripts are loaded?

Comment: @xiaohan2012 There is a hack. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript/48240128#48240128

Comment: This is not actually an accurate method to detect that the window has closed. The unload and beforeunload events are fired whenever the document within the window is unloaded, which could be due to a redirect or reload, for instance. See @DustinHoffner's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240128/51055) for an accurate method.

Comment: It won't work with redirects as well, so suppose if you have an OAuth flow then even if your redirect URI has the same domain it won't work.

Answer (score 161):

While the accepted answer is correct for same origins I found a solution for cross origin popups:

```
var win = window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    if(win.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert('closed');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Source: [atashbahar.com](http://atashbahar.com/post/2010-04-27-detect-when-a-javascript-popup-window-gets-closed)

**For those considering using it.**

Even Facebook is using this "hack" in their [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript).

You can verify this by having a look at their code. Just search for `.closed` in https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is specifically a hack for cross-origin, it's actually the only accurate way to detect that the window has closed. The unload and beforeunload events are fired whenever the document within the window is unloaded, which could be due to a redirect or reload so it doesn't necessarily mean the window was closed.

Comment: This does not appear to work in Microsoft Edge, unfortunately

Comment: I just tested it on IE11 - WIN7:

`var win = window.open('https://www.google.com/')`

When the user allows popups the `win` variable will contain the expected object.

Of course you have to call this with a user-triggered event. (e.g. `onClick` on something)

Comment: I've just tested the solution using Edge (March 2021) where I was monitoring window closed events for the same domain i.e. additional windows opened then closed within my app and this works nicely!

Comment: Be aware! If the popup is blocked, this setInterval will run INFINITELY

Comment: Doesn't seem to work win.closed is set true without closing the window.

Comment: This approach works for me, however win.close  sets as true even when the URL inside the opened window(win) gets changed.  Is there a way to avoid it and only execute when the win gets actually closed?
@DustinHoffner

Answer (score 13):

The event name is `onbeforeunload` and not `onBeforeUnload`. JS is case sensitive.

Comment: if we attach events by using on it attaches it as inline property to html and html is incase sensitive what means this will make absolutely no difference

Answer (score 10):

You need to bind the `onbeforeunload` event to the window AFTER it is opened.

The simplest way to do that would be to have the javascript onbeforeunload code within the window source code.

For detailed explanations, refer to these two very similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270395/870729) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270395/870729) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you.  Indeed `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` MUST be bounded AFTER the child window has loaded to work correctly.

Answer (score 6):

`onbeforeunload` event **must** be added **after** loading of pop-up window. For example, you can add it at the end of its load event like below;

```
const new_window = window.open('some url')
new_window.onload = function(){ 
    /* my code */ 
    this.onbeforeunload = function(){ /* my code */ }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably do not want to overwrite the value of `onbeforeunload`, because this will interfere with the popout's handler if it also uses that hook.

Use `addEventListener('beforeunload', ...)` instead.

```js
const wnd = window.open(theUrl)
wnd.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Please note, other options exists for events, such as `unload` and `pageHide`.  Read docs to see what event is best for your implementation.

For reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event

For an overview of the page lifecycle, see:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#developer-recommendations-for-each-state

Answer (score 4):

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const usePopupWindow = ({
  url,
  onPopupClose,
  popupProperties = "width=200,height=200",
}) => {
  const timer = useRef();

  const handleWindowPopup = () => {
    const windowPopup = window.open(url, "popup", popupProperties);

    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (windowPopup.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer.current);
        onPopupClose();
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
  }, []);

  return { handleWindowPopup };
};

export default usePopupWindow;
```

Created this hook for React use case

Comment: window.closed fires as soon as the popup opens and not after.

Comment: @JohnsonFashanu I am not seeing that behavior in chrome FWIW.  Where you using a different browser?

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you need to bind the onbeforeunload event to the window *after* it is opened.

See example in other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25989253/578275.

Answer (score -1):

```
var new_window = window.open('some_url')
```

You can also check if `new_window.window` is `null`. But you need to manually check it with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions.

This is btw the only way how to check it when you are not on the same domain.

Comment: This is useful if you have a global method that opens and manages windows for you, and the url may be internal or external depending on the context