# change event not firing after setting value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind change event to textarea(read only) whenever its value is set dynamically by opening popup window.

I am able to set the value, but the change event is not getting fired.

I used below code to bind change event to textarea :

```
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').bind("change", onChangeCordinator);
function onChangeCordinator(){}
```

Comment: can you clarify the term "whenever its value is set". There are a multitude of possibilites to check this, i.e. blur() events

Comment: its value is set using onclick event on button...which opens the popup window

Comment: still not sure about what you are trying to achieve, could you please insert a bit of html code to clarify the situation (if the answers are not sufficent yet)

Comment: With later versions of Jquery, the bind function is deprecated.  You can use the "on" function instead.

Comment: actually i am still using 1.4 :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you setting the value? By default the change event fires only if the value is changed by the browser user.

If you are setting the value programatically you need to use `.trigger('change')`

So somewhere in your onclick handler you need:

```
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Sorry it may sound wrong...when should i trigger the function??

Comment: Wherever and whenever you are changing the value.

Comment: Actually i am using popup window to get the value...and i don't have access to that code (and cant modify it)...is there anyway around i can trigger that function...maybe using window focus function or some other??

Comment: You are using the popup to **get** the value. Are you also using it to **set** the value? If so, I presume the popup page is on the same domain? If yes, you can use `onbeforeunload` like here: [capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah i just saw that...thanks for the advice...now testing it... :)

Answer (score 3):

there is a syntax error in your js

change this to

```
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').bind("change", onChangeCordinator);});
```

this

```
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').bind("change", onChangeCordinator);
```

**UPDATE:**

well you need to trigger it manually after setting the value on textarea like this

```
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').val('Set Your Value Here').trigger('change');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XP35b/)

Comment: oh sorry...it was a mistake...i m using this line only
$('textarea[name="Cordinator"]').bind("change", onChangeCordinator);

Comment: Actually i am using popup window to get the value...and i don't have access to that code (and cant modify it)...is there anyway around i can trigger that function...maybe using window focus function or some other??