# Run code after window close

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am writing an application in asp.net (vb), I am having a problem wher textboxvalue is being set before the window open has been closed by the user is there a way of preventing this?

```
 Sub btnSelectDate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectDate.Click

    Dim Window As String
    Window = " window.open('About.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500'); "

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "date", Window, True)

    textboxvalue.Text = "hello"

    Page_Load()



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text of textboxvalue after the popup window has closed, you can do it in the client code (see [Capture the close event of popup window in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript)):

```
    Dim jsCode As String
    jsCode = "var wnd = window.open('About.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500'); wnd.onbeforeunload = function() { document.getElementById('textboxvalue').value = 'Hello'; };"
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "date", jsCode, True)
```

Here I assume that *textboxvalue* is the actual ID of the TextBox in the rendered HTML.

UPDATE - To process the button click in client code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" OnClientClick="ProcessSelectDate(); return false;" />

<script>
    function ProcessSelectDate()
    {
        var wnd = window.open('About.aspx', 'MsgWindow', 'width=500, height=500');
        wnd.onbeforeunload = function () { document.getElementById('textboxvalue').value = 'Hello'; var form = document.forms['form1']; form.submit(); };
    }
</script>
```

Where form1 is the ID of the form.

Comment: Could i call the page_load in the javascript too?

Comment: In order to call server-side code, you would have to submit the form or run some AJAX command (I am not very familiar with AJAX).

Comment: By the way, if everything is done in client code, you could eliminate the btnSelectDate_Click server-side procedure completely, and use the OnClientClick attribute of btnSelectDate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1- In the script file that closes the window add the following code

`window.opener.location.href = "YouPage?FromPopup=1"`

2- from Parent window check

```
Request.QueryString["FromPopup"]
```

where you can add code