# alert before close(x) button in chrome modal popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i want to close the popup modal confirm alert but above code is not working.
I also tried `popupcsd.onbeforeunload` and `popupcsd.onUnload` but not working

var popupcsd  = `window.open('www.example.com', 'CSD ', 'width=1000, height=800');`

```
    
    var popupcsd =window.open('www.example.com', 'CSD ', 'width=1000, height=800');

    popupcsd.beforeunload = function(){
                    console.log('leaving page'); // Use 'Preserve Log' option in 
    Console
                    alert('alert');
                    return leavingPageText;
                }
```

am working this code in `Angular JS`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9388380/5621827

Comment: popup window url is different. so its not happened

Comment: popup window url is different doamin is `www.domain.com` and popup url is `www.example.com`

Comment: @jitender looks like duplicate but actually, please see above comment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of beforeunload use onbeforeunload

```
popupcsd.onbeforeunload = function(){
    console.log('leaving page');                    
    alert('alert');
    return leavingPageText;
}
```

I tried and its working on my end

Comment: popup window url is different doamin is `www.domain.com` and popup url is `www.example.com`

Comment: That should not make a difference. You can open any site using window.open

Answer (score 0):

Callback name that you have used is wrong. It should be changed as below.

```
 popupcsd.onbeforeunload instead of popupcsd.beforeunload
```

Comment: popup window url is different doamin is `www.domain.com` and popup url is `www.example.com`