# How to trigger an event in React after an opened window closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window

I have a div in React with an onClick handler that when clicked implements window.open in a pop-up window that directs them to an external URL. When the user closes the pop-up window, I would like to implement an API call. However, everything I've tried has failed, including attempting to use event listeners.

How can I detect when a window is closed in React?

The current code I have for the window event is as follows:

```
export class App extends Component {

  opener = () => {
    const myWindow = window.open("https://www.espn.com", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  }

  render() {  

    return (
      <div onClick={this.opener}>
        Hello World
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change the `opener` function as below:

```
  opener = () => {
    const myWindow = window.open("https://www.espn.com", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");

    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
        if(myWindow.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            alert('closed');
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240128/1632961) | [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQwjgN)