# Can you drag a javascript panel outside browser window?

Tags: javascript, html

I mean, you can drag a JPanel outside the window border, shown in the picture here:
[JPanel outside window border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT94u.png)

Can you do it with javascript? If you can, how do you do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, you can't.

Comment: I see. Any alternatives that i can use?

Comment: You could have a button and when you click on it, it opens a popup window with the panel in it, then hide the panel in the original window, when the popup is closed, show the panel again (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought. Thank you for the suggestions.