# Need to run some code before closing of a popup window in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window, onbeforeunload

I am opening a popup chrome window.

```
let popup = window.open(redirectUrl, '_blank');
```

I want to take the variable set in the localstorage in that window, before it closes. I have written code as

```
popup.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
   console.log(popup.localStorage.abc);
}
```

But this line is not getting executed. I debugged,Debugger is not even going inside the method. Please help me in what I am doing wrong or is there any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture the close event of popup window in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript)

Comment: I have tried the other method also, by setting time interval. But it is not giving me localStorage access

Comment: Are you perhaps opening a pop up for different domain? If you are then it is simply impossible for security reasons