# How can we store the reference of a value, rather than copying the value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In Javascript, how can i store the reference of a value, rather than copying the value?

Suppose i created a window popup using `const popup = window.popup(url, config)` and that if i want to check if that popup is closed, i can just console.log `popup.closed`.

This would return a boolean value depending on the state of the popup.
All Cool.

Now, in vuejs 3, I want to look for changes in this value to trigger a function.

What i did is, I created a data property `isClosed` and assigned value as `false` (becasue after opening a popup, & checking, closed would be `false`) like below:

```js
data() {
    return {
        isClosed: false
    }
}
```

Now after creating a popup, i assigned this `isClosed` to `popup.closed`:

```js
this.isClosed = popup.closed
```

Now what I was doing is, I added a watcher property to trigger a function when the value is changed:

```js
watch: {
    isClosed() {
        console.log("value changed");
        // the function to trigger here
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, its not even logging when i close that popup. Then i realised its just copying the value of popup.closed rather making a ref.

So, how can i possibly do this without `setInterval` ?

---

What I'm doing now is, I'm reassigning that `isClosed` data property every 3sec so that it would change the value of `isClosed` & trigger the watcher & thus trigger the function.

```js
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.isClosed = popup.closed;
    if (this.isClosed) {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
}, 3000)
```

But the big blow on my face is, why use a watcher when we can just add the function to trigger inside this timer, to trigger when the value of `popup.closed` is true.

So, how can i store the reference of a the popup.value, rather than copying the value?

Comment: You cannot do that in JavaScript. You can save the reference to `popup` and check the `closed` property, as you did in your question, but you cannot create a reference to a variable or object property value.

Comment: For doing that kind of thing (not sure it will work for a popup), you might want to look at [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Ok let me check that

Comment: Can't use mutation observers as we are opening a new window, if it was an element we are adding in the dom, that would have worked. Thanks for the suggestion though, as i could learn a new topic.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388380/capture-the-close-event-of-popup-window-in-javascript . setInterval is a workaround that may be acceptable as a fallback. Not directly related to Vue as native APIs obviously don't have vue reactivity. "why use a watcher" - you probably don't have to, but if you need to react to the *changes* in open/close state with no multiple calls, that's the place where you can do that

Comment: @EstusFlask, thanks for reply. Saw that post already, but i thought there might be a better way rather using setInterval. I understand the use of watcher, but i was not able to use it for my use case, then thought about posting the question here.

Comment: @SoorajSPrakash There may be a better way depending on your case, this is reflected in the answers