# How can I prevent a page unload with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my program, if a user tries to leave a page, he'll receive a dialog box asking if he is sure he wants to leave.

How should I implement the 'cancel' option if the user chooses not to leave the page?

Source javascript code:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
   var c= confirm ("Are you sure?");
   if (c){
       alert("Thanks. Good luck!");
   }
   else{
       ????
   }
});
```

Comment: ONLY prompt the user if there are any kind of unsaved changes etc. NEVER EVER thank them with another alert dialog etc when they leave, it's the worst possible UX case.

Comment: Thanks, I am agree. It is a very good advice when I think about it now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

many question about this in stackoverflow
[How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

[JavaScript + onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270395/javascript-onbeforeunload)

Comment: Then why did not you flag the question as a duplicate?

Comment: i dont want to redirect him to other page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    var value = navigateAway(isDirty);
    if(value=="changed")`enter code here`
    {
        if(jQuery("#saveCheck").val()=="false")
        {
            return "<?php echo JText::_('OVR_WANT_TO_LEAVE');?>";
        }
    }

 });
```