# error with onunload event

Tags: javascript

I've got a problem with the `onunload` event testing script
it must fire only on the window `onunload`
but it fires with load as well.. Why?
There is something wrong, and I don't know what it is..
Please help

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(){alert("welcome to my page");}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="hello()" >
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the script code

```
window.onunload = goodbye();
function goodbye(){
alert("Thank you for visiting.come back soon!");
}
//window.addEventListener('unload',goodbye(),false);
```

I've tried the inline calling with body tag, the `window.onunload` calling and the listener calling.
Nothing works correctly, and I get the "Thank you for visiting. come back soon!" message when the page first loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
window.onunload = goodbye();
```

This sets the `window.unload` event equal to the result of the `goodbye()` function, and calls the `goodbye()` function immediately. Change this to:

```
window.onunload = goodbye;
```

**IN MORE DETAIL:**

You call a function by naming it, and passing it zero or more parameters in brackets (eg: `goodbye()`). When you call a function, it is called immediately, and, if it is used as part of a statement (rather than the whole statement), then ther return value of the function is used where the call was made. So, what you're saying with the line:

```
window.onunload = goodbye();
```

is: "fetch me the result of calling the `goodbye` function, and assign the return value to the `window.onunload` variable". Calling the `goodbye` function pops up an alert, but returns null, so you are, in effect, saying, "pop up an alert right now, and then set the `window.onunload` variable to null".

The `window.onunload` variable (and all other event variables) expects to be a function, so what you actually want to say here is, "set the `window.onunload` function to be the `goodbye` function, so when the system calls the `onunload` event, it will call the `goodbye` function", and to do that, you assign the function itself to the variable:

```
window.onunload = goodbye;
```

**HOWEVER**

The `onunload` event is probably not what you're looking for. This only fires after the page has been unloaded, so most of the UI components are not available to your anymore, including `alert`. Try looking into `onbeforeunload` instead ([JavaScript + onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270395/javascript-onbeforeunload))

Comment: thanks ..... i've tried it but no msg appears at all. do i need to return the alert ?

Comment: thank you sooooooo ..... the concept is clear now, and the function runs on it's right place and time :) you rocks

Comment: now i got another question ... the window.onbeforeunload = goodbye; works only for mozilla firefox .... why the respond of browsers differ to the onunload and onbeforeunlad events ..... what to do when i need the goodbye function to be executed in all browsers ?